# Facebook Login callback not working in titanium

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, titanium

I am trying implement facebook login in titanium app. Login is working but callback method is not calling when the user is login or logout.

I have added module.
Added the key in tiapp.xml

Then i have coded this in .js file

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.appid = 11111111111111;
fb.permissions = ['public_profile','email'];
fb.forceDialogAuth = true;


var fbLogin = fb.createLoginButton({
    top : '25%',
    style : fb.BUTTON_STYLE_WIDE,
    zIndex : 10
});


fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
      if (e.success) {
         alert('Logged In');
      } else if (e.error) {
         alert(e.error);
     } else if (e.cancelled) {
         alert("Canceled");
     }
     console.log("Outside ");
});

fb.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
    alert('Logged out');
});
win.add(fbLogin);
```

Comment: Titanium sdk version?

Comment: Sdk Version 3.5.1.GA

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `fb.initialize()` at the end of the file.